# TFS source control mapping in Visual Studio 2013. Unable to add project to a solution

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I am very new to using TFS, I don't have all the knowledge about TFS and I am running into a serious problem. I hope somebody will help me to fix this problem. Please find details about my problem in next paragraph.

I have a two solutions which are added in TFS. Each solution has more than one projects in it. I am using solution 1's project in solution 2. I added project from solution1 to solution2 from TFS which I mapped to solution 2's local project path.

Now I took solution 2 to my local path from TFS and updated mapping path for that project which I already added in solution 1 whose mapping was different when I added it to solution 1.

Now the project from solution 2 is not loading in solution 1, when I tried to add it from local path from solution 2. It is searching for that project from solution 2 in solution 1, which is modified and is now available at solution 2's local path.

How do I fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: The location of the shared project needs to be the same for both solutions, they should both refer to the same project in the local file system.

Comment: Yes, that is what i want to do. I will try to use same location for both projects. I will use solution 1's path. Thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing projects between solutions is possible as long as you reference the projects by a relative path.

The easiest way to do this is by putting the two solutions in a shared folder in TFS and then mapping this shared folder to a local path on your machine. As long as everyone uses this Shared folder on their local development pc, all paths will be correct.

On a side note, another way of sharing compiled assemblies between solutions is by using [NuGet packages](http://docs.nuget.org/). Maybe that's overkill for your situation but it's definitely something you can look into.

Comment: Thanks @Wouter de Kort.